# Ubuntuでlibgtk-x11-2.0.so.0を追加するには

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntuでkompozerを実行しようとした際に以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
$ sh kompozer
./kompozer-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

この問題となっているファイルはどうすれば追加することができるのでしょうか。

Comment: `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` が含まれているのは `libgtk2.0-dev` パッケージですので、`sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev` としてインストールすると良いかもしれません。

Comment: やってみましたが相変わらず同じエラーがでてしまいます

Comment: KompoZer はもはや骨董品の類だと思いますので、動かすのは少し面倒かも知れませんね。Ubuntu のバージョンはいくつですか？ また、何ビット（32bit / 64bit）のシステムですか？ 実行しようとしている`kompozer` のバージョンはいくつですか？

Comment: 参考までに、KompoZerはベータ版(0.8b3)のリリースが2010年を最後に更新が止まっていますが、KompoZerと同じくNvu派生のソフトとして [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) というソフトもあり、こちらは比較的最近(2017年)のリリースがあります。なお、無料でも利用できますが一部機能は有償ライセンスをアクティベートする形になるようです。

Answer (score 2):

多少環境は異なるかと思いますが、参考までに情報を共有しておきます。

**実行環境**
Linux Mint 17 Qiana 32bit (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 相当)
KompoZer-0.8b3 (PPAリポジトリの追加ではうまくダウンロード出来なかったので、kompozer, kompozer-data パッケージを以下から入手)

[kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/12.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb.html)
[kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/12.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb.html)

---

**確認手順**
質問で`kompozer`実行時にエラーで表示されている`libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`がどのパッケージに入っているかを`apt-file`コマンドで調べます。`dpkg`コマンドを使用した場合は**インストール済み**ファイルに対してのみ検索が可能。未インストールのパッケージも含めて検索したい場合は`apt-file`コマンドを使用します。

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ apt-file update
$ apt-file search libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk2.0-0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk2.0-0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23
libgtk2.0-0-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23
```

`libgtk2.0-0`パッケージに含まれていることが分かったので、こちらをインストールします。

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

インストールされたファイルの確認。

```
$ dpkg -L libgtk2.0-0 | grep "so.0"
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

---

ちなみに、`libgtk2.0-dev`のようにパッケージ名に**dev**が付くものは、大抵アプリケーション開発時に必要なヘッダファイル(`*.h`)をまとめたパッケージです。
アプリを動作させるのに必要なのは共有ライブラリ(`*.so`)の方なので、単にアプリを起動させるだけなら必ずしもヘッダファイルは必要ありません。